# Is FLOP calculated by tf.profiler.profile per second or per step?

Tags: tensorflow, flops

I am wondering the total flops counted by this function:

```
tf.profiler.profile(tf.get_default_graph(),options=tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation())
```

is per second or per step?